# Setting up a private network for XenDesktop

Tags: networking, xenserver, xendesktop

What I'm trying to do is set up and test out XenServer and XenDesktop. What I've done so far is install XenServer and  Windows7 with XenCenter on two machines.  I've successfully been able to create VM's from XenCenter so that's a good sign.  The problem I'm running into is setting up XenDesktop.

I've set up a VM running Windows Server 2008 R2 on which I want to install XenDesktop.  I know XenDesktop requires Active Directory, so I installed the Active Directory role on the server and currently, from what it seems like, it isn't working while I'm connnected directly to our work network because our network is filtering out any Active Directory traffic coming from the VM.  So my idea was to set up my own private network behind a switch on which I'll have my testing computers running.  That way none of the traffic will be blocked.

So I put the switch in and connected my two test machines to it.  So from what I understand I'm going to want to up static IP's for all my machines in my test network, but whenever I try they're unable to communicate with each other.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's a lot of questions. You need to get back to basics - get an unmanaged switch, stay away from your corporate LAN and build a Server 2008 R2 Domain Controller with DHCP and DNS and go from there.